# Adding tags "vanilla" to Minecraft questions?

Tags: discussion

Sometimes certain users ask for help in questions that obviously have different solutions, depending on the version.  With this in mind, should anyone answering Minecraft questions cover their answers with both Vanilla and NonVanilla versions?

For example, with [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/96413/ive-lost-my-portal-from-the-end-to-the-over-world/96416#96416), the focus is unclear.  Does he want a solution only found within Minecraft (ala Vanilla) or does he want 3rd party program help?

Questions should be tagged with vanilla to differentiate that they're not using 3rd party programs for solutions and rather fixing things within the domain Minecraft has.

Comment: The assumption should be that if just the core tag is used, then it's vanilla, I would think.

Comment: then what differentiates between the user wanting a vanilla solution or a nonvanilla?

Comment: This is a bad solution for the same reason that using platform tags to delineate that console/mod solutions to [tag:skyrim] questions are unwanted -  it invites piles of duplicates and bad/non-answers to pileup. If a question can be answered both with and without the use of a tool that isn't availiable to all players of a game, then that question should get multiple answers (or one really comprehensive one). It's why the SE engine allows for multiple answers in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think so.

The issue you're poking at is trying to gauge the intent of the user - were they looking for a 3rd - party solution, an in-game cheat engine (a la Skyrim's console), or a "vanilla" answer.

And the issue then is, if the user didn't specify which of these they were looking for, do you think they'd have the foresight to look for a tag other than that of the game? There's an issue here of burden of knowledge - those most likely to ask for a specifically "vanilla" solution are those who are already aware of other alternatives.

Ultimately, I don't see a benefit from having a tag suffix to exclude certain answers, especially since the suggested suffix is non-obvious.